# JSDoc property name containing period

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

How can I document the property of an object in JSDoc / VSCode when it contains a period?

For example:

```
/**
 * @type {PersonObject}
 */
let personObject = {
   "first.last": "John Doe", // optional
   "age": 31
}

/**
 * @typedef {Object} PersonObject
 * @property {String} [first.last]
 * @property {Number} age
 */
```

> {
>       "message": "Type '{\"first.last\": string; age: number; }' is not assignable to type 'PersonObject'.\n  Object literal may only specify known properties, and '\"first.last\"' does not exist in type 'PersonObject'.",
>       "source": "ts",
>   }

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Closure Compiler, or at least a JSDoc flavor that its compatible with:

I suggest using the [new @typedef syntax](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-Types#typedef) it seems to [work in this example](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540formatting%2520pretty_print%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520ADD%2520YOUR%2520CODE%2520HERE%250A%250A%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540typedef%2520%2520%257B%257B%250A%2520*%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520first.last%253Astring%252C%250A%2520*%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520age%253Anumber%252C%250A%2520*%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%257D%250A%2520*%252F%250Avar%2520PersonObject%253B%250A%250A%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540type%2520%257BPersonObject%257D%250A%2520*%252F%250Alet%2520personObject%2520%253D%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2522first.last%2522%253A%2520%2522John%2520Doe%2522%252C%2520%252F%252F%2520optional%250A%2520%2520%2520%2522age%2522%253A%252031%250A%257D%250A).

```
/**
 * @typedef  {{
 *            first.last:string,
 *            age:number,
 *          }}
 */
var PersonObject;

/**
 * @type {PersonObject}
 */
let personObject = {
   "first.last": "John Doe", // optional
   "age": 31
}
```

Note that when you change 'first.last' in either place, Closure will emit a [warning](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540formatting%2520pretty_print%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520ADD%2520YOUR%2520CODE%2520HERE%250A%250A%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540typedef%2520%2520%257B%257B%250A%2520*%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520first.last%253Astring%252C%250A%2520*%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520age%253Anumber%252C%250A%2520*%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%257D%250A%2520*%252F%250Avar%2520PersonObject%253B%250A%250A%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540type%2520%257BPersonObject%257D%250A%2520*%252F%250Alet%2520personObject%2520%253D%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2522firstzzzzz%2522%253A%2520%2522John%2520Doe%2522%252C%2520%252F%252F%2520optional%250A%2520%2520%2520%2522age%2522%253A%252031%250A%257D%250A):

```
JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: initializing variable
found   : {age: number, firstzzzzz: string}
required: {age: number, first.last: string}
missing : [first.last]
mismatch: [] at line 14 character 19
let personObject = {
```